# JS 'onclick' handler prevents ':hover' CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I recently added an onclick event to one of my divs and now the :hover css for that div is not working. Any thoughts on how to get around this?

It's done with KnockoutJS, but I don't think that's an issue here. It might be.

Comment: example , fiddle, code? how can w replicate the issue

Comment: I've never heard of such a behavior. Please show us your code.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: I'll try and reproduce with a fiddle, give me a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `:hover` css style may have been overridden.

Comment: Knockout was adding a class that was killing the hover. Wouldn't have thought about it if you all hadn't pointed out that it is abnormal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us the code...what is your on click event doing exactly? Is it effecting that div in a similar manner to what is going on in the CSS??